# VPS Ubuntu 20 Python3 requests Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, vps, ubuntu-20.04

I had a bit of code that worked perfectly in my windows PC, but after I uploaded it to a VPS running Ubuntu version 20 it stopped working. So, I oversimplified the problem trying to run a single request as follows

```
import requests

url = "https://www.adidas.es/api/plp/content-engine?query=ultraboost-hombre"
headers = {
          'authority': 'www.adidas.es',
          'x-instana-t': 'd822fbb23a5415d6',
          'x-instana-s': 'd822fbb23a5415d6',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
          'x-instana-l': '1,correlationType=web;correlationId=d822fbb23a5415d6',
          'accept': '*/*',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
          'referer': 'https://www.adidas.es/ultraboost-hombre',
          'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
          }
response=requests.get(url=url,headers=headers,data={})
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I have tried the following

`sudo python3 -m pip install "requests[security]"` and slightly different `pip3 install requests[security]` and nothing changed

For further info, typing this `python3 -m requests.help` returns

```
{
  "chardet": {
    "version": "3.0.4"
  },
  "cryptography": {
    "version": "3.0"
  },
  "idna": {
    "version": "2.8"
  },
  "implementation": {
    "name": "CPython",
    "version": "3.8.2"
  },
  "platform": {
    "release": "5.4.0-42-generic",
    "system": "Linux"
  },
  "pyOpenSSL": {
    "openssl_version": "1010107f",
    "version": "19.1.0"
  },
  "requests": {
    "version": "2.22.0"
  },
  "system_ssl": {
    "version": "1010106f"
  },
  "urllib3": {
    "version": "1.25.8"
  },
  "using_pyopenssl": true
}
```

I really have no clue as to why in the VPS a simple request is not working. Can somebody help here please?